# Sync/Replication of 2 Oracle Databases with NetApp storage

Tags: replication, oracle-11g, data-synchronization, oracle-enterprise-manager

I am working on a high availability setup of Oracle Enterprise Manager.  I need the back-end repository replicated (preferably in real time, or something close) to another repository, in which I could stand up a standby Oracle Enterprise Manager to point at it.  The idea is that if my primary setup goes down, I could switch to the standby without losing any monitoring or historical data.

The Oracle Databases (11.2.0.3) use NetApp storage devices.  The primary is configured as a RAC, but the standby would be a single instance.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  I would like to setup replication from the primary to the secondary in as close to real time as possible.  Also, the databases are about 500 miles away from each other...if that has any effect.  I am new to the DBA scenario, as I was given a task that I do not have a lot of familiarity with.  I could use some guidance in this area.  Thank you.

Update:  Sorry for that.  Our database is under the Oracle EE license.

Comment: Please edit your question to add if your RAC under Oracle EE license or under SE license.